# Switzerland: should I use Geschäftsführer instead of Direktor?

Tags: swiss-standard-german

I translated the French title **directeur** (which stands also for CEO) to the German word **Direktor**.

The professional translator I work with suggests that I stop using *Direktor* and use *Geschäftsführer* instead; she says that the latter is more widespread and that *Direktor* is antiquated (this is also what I understand from reading [Geschäftsfuhrer(in) or Direktorin](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35819/gesch%c3%a4ftsfuhrerin-or-direktorin)).

Now, is there a difference between how Swiss-German relate to the word *Direktor*? I understand that the *Swiss standard German* sometimes deviates from the German German (e.g. "parkieren" instead of "parken" or words taken over from the French language).

So, would it be better in Switzerland to use *Geschäftsführer* instead too?

Comment: Partly, but I need some insight with respect to the difference in Switzerland…

Comment: I don't think there's any difference in the DACH region. The term _Direktor_ is outdated.

Comment: The related question does ask about Germany only/not swiss specific. So I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm As I mentioned for this specific  case it's the same for Swiss and Austria as it is in Germany.